# Unable to include `linux/config.h` on 5.8 kernel

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

Originally I was trying to include `linux/config.h` to compile an old driver from source originated from the 2.6 kernel on the latest 5.8 kernel.

And here's the include part of this driver:

```
#include <linux/config.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>

#include <linux/kernel.h> /* printk() */
#include <linux/fs.h>     /* everything... */
#include <linux/types.h>  /* size_t */
#include <asm/uaccess.h>
```

And as per requested, I'm posting the Makefile here:

```
ifeq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)

    KERNELDIR ?= /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
    PWD := $(shell pwd)

modules:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) modules

modules_install:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) modules_install

clean:
    rm -rf *.o *~ core .depend .*.cmd *.ko *.mod.c .tmp_versions

.PHONY: modules modules_install clean

else
    obj-m := my_driver.o
endif
```

While I tried to compile this driver via gcc the compiler told me that `linux/config.h` could not been found.

I was told from the web to use `linux/autoconf.h` to replace `linux/config.h` but failed.

So I just wanna to know which file should I replace `linux/config.h` with to make this driver compiled and run.

Comment: Have you installed the kernel headers?

Comment: Kernel modules are compiled with a very special set of flags, which are usually supplied by a makefile. If this driver doesn't come with its own makefile, you better write one. Kernel driver tutorials around the net usually include a section on writing a makefile.

Comment: @AlanBirtles, Yes I've tried to install `linux-headers-generic (5.8.0.36.40)` but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: The header install didn't work or it just didn't fix your problem?

Comment: @AlanBirtles the installed header didn't provide any support for  `linux/config.h` or `linux/autoconf.h`

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I've updated the `Makefile` into the question

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Ah, Okay, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `linux/config.h` has not been needed since kernel 2.6.15. It was deprecated in kernel 2.6.15 and removed in kernel 2.6.19 (and also removed from some Red Hat 2.6.18 kernels). The following sequence may be used to conditionally include it:

```
#include <linux/version.h>
#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE < KERNEL_VERSION(2,6,15)
#include <linux/config.h>
#endif
```

The main kernel Makefile uses GCC's **-include *file*** option to automatically define the kernel configuration option macros without the use of an explicit `#include <linux/config.h>` (or its replacements) in the C source files. There is no need to add `#include <generated/autoconf.h>` or similar to the C source files.

Answer (score 2):

Well, after vast amount of Googling and DuckDuckGoing, I found the solution [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/568395/what-is-creating-the-generated-autoconf-h/568397).

The `linux/config.h` in kernel 2.6 and `linux/autoconf.h` was relocated to `generated/autoconf.h`

Simply replace `linux/config.h` with `generated/autoconf.h` would do the trick.